# Difference between finish() and super.finish() in Java?

Tags: java, android, super, difference

What are the main differences between using `finish()` and `super.finish()` in Java? 
When can/should you use one over the other?

Comment: Try to google java "super" keyword

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`finish()` will call the `finish()` method *on your class*.

`super.finish()` will call the `finish()` method *on your parent class*.

Unless your are overriding the `finish()` method in your Activities (which you shouldn't), the two will do the exact same thing.

Answer (score 0):

finish() will call the finish() method on your class.

super.finish() will call the finish() method on your parent class

super is dedicated to parent class always.